# Switching view controllers in an extension

Tags: swift

so I have an extension here in my View controller, now what I am trying to add to the bottom of the extension is a @IBAction buttonTapped so my user can tap the button which then checks the photo is taken and then goes to the next view controller but it is not letting me add the @IBAction it says "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction"

what can I do so my user can tap a button which checks that the image is taken and then takes my user to the next view controller

```
    extension BackroundCheckViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
    UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //cancel
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                       
    }
    //pick an image
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo 
    info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                       
    //get the image the selected
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                           
    self.ProfilePictureImageView.image = pickedImage
                        
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        
    //upload to firebase
    PhotoService.savePhoto(image: pickedImage)
                    
                    }
                    
    // navigate to somewhere else
                    
                        
            }
                    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` in your main controller declaration, you can't add them in an extension.

```
class BackroundCheckViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Got the action here")
        if ProfilePictureImageView.image != nil {
            print("User has picked an image navigating to somewhere..")
            let myViewController = MyViewController()
            if let navigationController = navigationController {
                navigationController.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
            } else {
                present(myViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and after I add them into my main controller declaration what code do I type so they know to only work once the user has selected an image?

Comment: Add a check in the action to see of the `imageView.image` is has an image, if it does navigate to another view controller. Check the updated code, I've added a sample.